# Optimize performance of a formula spanning three consecutive indices, with wraparound

Tags: r, performance, formula, apply, indices

I want to optimize the implementation of this formula.

Here is the formula: [image: formula]

`x` is an array of values. `i` goes from 1 to N where N > 2400000. 
For `i=0`, `i-1` is the last element and for `i=lastElement`, `i+1` is the first element. Here is the code which I have written:

```
   x <- 1:2400000
   re <- array(data=NA, dim = NROW(x))
   lastIndex = NROW(x)
   for(i in 1:lastIndex){
      if (i==1) {
        re[i] = x[i]*x[i] - x[lastIndex]*x[i+1]
      } else if(i==lastIndex) {
        re[i] = x[i]*x[i] - x[i-1]*x[1]
      } else {
        re[i] = x[i]*x[i] - x[i-1]*x[i+1]  
      }
    }
```

Can it be done by `apply` in R?

Comment: "Optimize it" for what? compactness (see my answer) performance? (use `data.table`)

Comment: Optimize w.r.t. performance.

Comment: Chetan, then you have to edit the title to say that. 'Optimize' is inherently ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use direct vectorization for this

```
# Make fake data
x <- 1:10
n <- length(x)
# create vectors for the plus/minus indices
xminus1 <- c(x[n], x[-n])
xplus1 <- c(x[-1], x[1])

# Use direct vectorization to get re
re <- x^2 - xminus1*xplus1
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Dason :)

Comment: This is creating three copies of a very large vector/array. You could avoid the copies with the padding trick, then `x[2:N]^2 - x[1:N-1]*x[3:N+1]`

Comment: @Chetan: this takes 3x the memory. If x is very large, then when you run out of memory, it will reduce the performance.

Answer (score 1):

If really each `x[i]` is equal to `i` then you can do a little math:
  xi^2 - (xi-1)*(xi+1) = 1
so all elements of the result are 1 (only the first and the last are not 1).
The result is:

```
c(1-2*N, rep(1, N-2), N*N-(N-1))
```

In the general case (arbitrary values in `x`) you can do (as in the answer from Dason):

```
x*x - c(x[N], x[-N])*c(x[-1], x[1])
```

Here is a solution with `rollapply()` from `zoo`:

```
library("zoo")
rollapply(c(x[length(x)],x, x[1]), width=3, function(x) x[2]^2 - x[1]*x[3]) # or:
rollapply(c(tail(x,1), x, x[1]), width=3, function(x) x[2]^2 - x[1]*x[3])
```

Here is the benchmark:

```
library("microbenchmark")
library("zoo")

N <- 10000
x <- 1:N

microbenchmark(
  math=c(1-2*N, rep(1, N-2), N*N-(N-1)), # for the data from the question
  vect.i=x*x - c(x[N], x[-N])*c(x[-1], x[1]), # general data
  roll.i=rollapply(c(x[length(x)],x, x[1]), width=3, function(x) x[2]^2 - x[1]*x[3]), # or:
  roll.tail=rollapply(c(tail(x,1), x, x[1]), width=3, function(x) x[2]^2 - x[1]*x[3])
)
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#      math    33.613    34.4950    76.18809    36.9130    38.0355   2002.152   100  a 
#    vect.i   188.928   192.5315   732.50725   197.1955   198.5245  51649.652   100  a 
#    roll.i 56748.920 62217.2550 67666.66315 68195.5085 71214.9785 109195.049   100   b
# roll.tail 57661.835 63855.7060 68815.91001 67315.5425 71339.6045 119428.718   100   b
```

Answer (score 0):

An lapply implementation of your formula would look like this:

```
x <- c(1:2400000) 
last <- length(x)

re <- lapply(x, function(i) {
    if(i == 1) {
        x[i]*x[i] - x[last]*x[i+1]
    } else if (i == last) {
        x[i]*x[i] - x[i-1]*x[1]
    } else {
        x[i]*x[i] - x[i-1]*x[i+1]  
    }
}) 

re <- unlist(re)
```

lapply will return a list, so conversion to a vector is done using unlist()

Comment: Use `sapply` instead of `lapply` which doesn't return a list but vector/matrix. Or even `vapply` knowing ahead the size and type of output

Answer (score 0):

1) You can avoid all the special-casing in the computation by padding the start and end of array x with copies of the last and first rows; something like this:

```
N <- NROW(x)
x <- rbind(x[N], x, x[1]) # pad start and end to give wraparound 

re <- lapply(2:N, function(i) { x[i]*x[i] - x[i-1]*x[i+1] } )
#re <- unlist(re) as andbov wrote

# and remember not to use all of x, just x[2:N], elsewhere
```

2) Directly vectorize, as @Dason's answer:

```
# Do the padding trick on x , then
x[2:N]^2 - x[1:N-1]*x[3:N+1]
```

3) If performance matters, I suspect using `data.table` or else for-loop on i will be faster, since it references three consecutive rows.

4) For more performance, **[use byte-compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237198/202229)**

5) If you need even more speed, **use Rcpp extension** (C++ under the hood) [How to use Rcpp to speed up a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223132/how-to-use-rcpp-to-speed-up-a-for-loop/29223316#29223316)

See those questions I cited for good examples of using lineprof and microbenchmarking to figure out where your bottleneck is.

Comment: Inside `lapply` shouldn't it be `2:N` instead of `x[2:N]`? Also, this is not performance efficient, takes a lot of time to run.

Comment: I liked the padding part. Smart move :)

Comment: @Chetan: add some random-seeded data to your question details so we can actually run an apples-to-apples comparison. *"It takes a lot of time to run"* is not specific, nor can any of the rest of us verify it. As to N>2.4 million, pick an actual value. I assume you're not blowing out your memory-limit; if you are, all bets are off.

Comment: Sure, 2:N, instead of x[2:N], whatever, the intent of the code is clear.

Comment: To the downvoter: there's a lot of work went into this, so tell me what you think needs improving.